# How to write an if condition which includes button pressed function in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift

I am passing an image from the phone library to a second view controller on the main view controller I have an image view integrated with a button and I need to write the code such that if there is no image selected from the library then the button pressed function should not work only when the image is loaded on to the image view of second view controller the button pressed function should be loaded else there should be no functionality to the button.
here is my code

```
if c != nil {

@IBAction func PicPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
    }
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let secondController = segue.destination as! MyStoryViewController
    secondController.s = c!
}

@IBAction func AddPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}  
}

extension ViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let Simage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage{
            c = Simage
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

and it's not working.

Comment: You could enable the button if only there is no image 
btn.isEnabled = (imageView.image == nil)

Comment: Hi and welcome.  Unfortunately it is difficult to understand your question entirely. Sentences and formatting your code would help.  You should also use more meaningful identifiers than `s` and `c`.  However, it would seem that the best approach would be to disable the button if no image was selected.

Comment: in which function should i enable the button @BassantAshraf

Comment: enable or disable after setting image to the imageView

Answer (score 0):

You cannot wrap an if-statement in an outlet.

**Inside** your button you can do like this:

```
If c != nil{
      performSegue(withIdentifier: ”segue”, sender: self)
}
```

Comment: @SAIANURAGDODDI  print the `c` and check the output. Probably always nil

Comment: yeah its always nil, so how to check whether the variable c consists an image or not

Comment: What variable c?

Comment: i am saving the image taken from library to a variable c, when we check if c is loaded with an image or not using the above condition it is always returning nil

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because you can't set image on imageview if it's not loaded yet because ImageView is IBOutlet it only show image in main thread not in Background thread. So, you can do one thing pass image object to secondViewController and set to imageView once the user redirect to SecondViewController like in ViewDidLoad().